# Find sublist in list with different scaling / fuzzy pattern recognition

Tags: python, pattern-recognition, list-comparison

I have two lists, each containing an ordered set of numbers.

One list is small (~ 5 - 20 elements) the other one is large (~ 5000). The lists have a different "scaling" and there might be points missing in one or the other list. In general most elements will be in both lists.

**I'm looking for a method to detect the position and the "scaling" between the two lists, such that the distance between the two lists has a minimum.**

An example would be:

```
l1 = [ 100.,  200., 400.]
l2 = [ 350., 1000., 2003., 3996., 7500., 23000.]
```

The scale would be 10. and the position of l1 in l2 is 1.

The list 10.*l1 appears at position 1 within l2; the lists have a distance of 7 (this depends on the metric I choose, here I just summed up the differences between all elements).

**I'm wondering if there are already methods out there e.g. in pattern recognition which I can use (preferably in python). It seems to me that this could be a common problem when comparing patterns with unknown scaling factors. But I couldn't find a good keyword which describes my problem.**

The application of this is to identify measured spectroscopic lines by comparing them to a catalog of the positions of known lines and therefore converting the unphysical unit "pixel on the detector" to actual wavelength.

In principle I could already provide a decent guess of the scaling factor of the two lists, but I guess this will not be necessary, as the solutions should be unique in most cases.

any help is appreciated,

Julian

Comment: I believe keywords that might apply to your problem are `regression` and/or `fitting`. I'm almost certain this can be done with NumPy, possibly using [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://glowingpython.blogspot.ch/2012/03/linear-regression-with-numpy.html) or [`numpy.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html). This is not my area of expertise at all however, so I hope some of the NumPy / SciPy guys can leave an educated answer.

Comment: I don't think that I can use a simple regression algorithm, because the distance between the two lists is not a continous function of the scale. Depending on the scale the "next neighbour" elements in the second list will change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're trying to solve is an optimization in two degrees. The first being the scale and the second being the index. The broad sense of your problem is generally difficult to solve efficiently. However there are a few things that could simplify the calculations. First are both sets sorted? Second are you looking for the consecutive set from the second list that matches the first or not? To explain that further I'll use an example: 1, 2, 3 and 2, 3, 4, 6. is the scale better as 2 (skipping the 3 in the second list) or 1.something (not skipping the 3)? Third what is the weighting you want to use to measure the difference between the two (linear sum, root mean square, etc.)?

If you can provide some of these details I may be able to give you a better idea of some things to try.

**UPDATE**

So based on your comment you can skip values. That actually makes this problem very difficult to solve O(2^n). Because you are basically looking at all combinations of list one with list two.

Even though you can optimize some aspects of this problem because they are sorted you will still have to check a lot of combinations.

Comment: Both sets are sorted.
Regarding your example: the scale 2 would be better than 1.x, because 1,2,3 would then exactly match 2,4,6.
Actually I'm not sure about the weighting. I think rms might be a good metric.